# Can't trigger POST-method form from outside <form>

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http-post

As a part of a game, i'm looking to assign values (dymaically) to a html-form, and then "POST" them on to the views.py for further actions (not really important)

My problem is that i can't seem to trigger the POST-part of my form, from outside it. Eh.

Code:

JS:

```
var score,x;

    function setScore(x){
        score=x;
        alert(score);
    }

    function getScore(){
        return score;
    }


    function postIt()   {       
        form = document.createElement('postForm');

        document.getElementById('userField').value = "Testing Name";
        document.getElementById('scoreField').value = score;
        alert(score);

        form.submit();   
    }
```

and html:

```
     <form action="" method="post" id="postForm">{% csrf_token %}
     <input type="hidden" id="userField" name="user"></input> Namn.<br>
     <input type="hidden" id="scoreField" name="score"></input> Score.<br>

     <button onclick="postIt()">Shoot</button>

<a href="javascript:setScore(1)">1</a> -     
<a href="javascript:setScore(2)">2</a> - 
<a href="javascript:setScore(3)">3</a> -
<a href="javascript:setScore(4)">4</a> -
<a href="javascript:setScore(5)">5</a> -
<a href="javascript:setScore(6)">6</a>   

<p>
<span onclick="postIt()">Skicka</span>   
     </form>
```

Problem is that i get the suspected result from the button, but not the span-'trigger'.

Expected, and correct, terminal window print (after i've assigned 3 as the score):

```
Testing Name
3
[20/May/2012 03:41:43] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1854
```

I can't really see why, though, since they're both connected to the same function..?

Comment: This has nothing to do with django. Getting rid of that tag.

Comment: why form = document.createElement('postForm'); shouldn't it be getElementById?

Comment: Short answer: in the end, i'll be stuck with some 50 or so, forms, that should be able to interact regardless of eachother. So i thought i't be neat to generate them on the fly..

Comment: Can you clarify what you hope to gain by creating the < form > on the fly? (Seems to me like extra work for no good reason; I must be missing something.) An advantage of using just one form is you can put some kind of ID in it just once, and that field's contents will be re-sent every time (so you can easily differentiate two clients at the same time). If you have 50 different operations, I'd use just one form and add another field < input type="hidden" id="operationField" name="operation" > then set its "value" to the 50 different possibilities (init? add? subract? close? etc.?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function postIt()   {       
        var form = document.getElementById('postForm');

        document.getElementById('userField').value = "Testing Name";
        document.getElementById('scoreField').value = score;
        alert(score);

        form.submit();   
    }
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ztw8r/1/)

The reason the button is working is because when you click it, you observe it's default behaviour which is to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
function postIt()   {       
    form = document.createElement('postForm');

    document.getElementById('userField').value = "Testing Name";
    document.getElementById('scoreField').value = score;
    alert(score);
    form.appendChild(document.getElementById('userField'));
    form.appendChild(document.getElementById('scoreField'));
    form.submit();   
}
```

Comment: There is no need to query the DOM twice.

Comment: I know, but I'm not here to fully optimize his code, just giving a solution to a problem that he will adapt... I do care though to transmit an idea, in this case I did